# Javascript show / hide on dropdown onchange function, need to remember the value after form submit

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form field with a select dropdown 1,7 and this onchange shows 1,7 fieldsets with three inputs, this is great until i validate the form, then i need to have a function that gets the post value from the dropdown and show again the correct number of fieldsets

So i need to add something to the function but i'm not sure the best way

I have the function below for the on change of the dropdown, on page reload i need to show the correct number of fieldsets using the POST value of the dropdown
Any ideas would be very helpful, not great with javascript!

```
$(function() {
$('#plaat1 , #plaat2, #plaat3, #plaat4, #plaat5, #plaat6, 
#plaat7').hide(); 
$('#plaatnum').change(function(){


    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '0') {
        $('#plaat1').hide();
        $('#plaat2').hide();
        $('#plaat3').hide();
        $('#plaat4').hide();
        $('#plaat5').hide();
        $('#plaat6').hide();
        $('#plaat7').hide();
    } 


    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '1') {
        $('#plaat1').show();
        $('#plaat2').hide();
        $('#plaat3').hide();
        $('#plaat4').hide();
        $('#plaat5').hide();
        $('#plaat6').hide();
        $('#plaat7').hide();
    } 

    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '2') {
        $('#plaat1').show();
        $('#plaat2').show();
        $('#plaat3').hide();
        $('#plaat4').hide();
        $('#plaat5').hide();
        $('#plaat6').hide();
        $('#plaat7').hide();
    } 

    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '3') {
        $('#plaat1').show();
        $('#plaat2').show();
        $('#plaat3').show();
        $('#plaat4').hide();
        $('#plaat5').hide();
        $('#plaat6').hide();
        $('#plaat7').hide();
    } 

    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '4') {
        $('#plaat1').show();
        $('#plaat2').show();
        $('#plaat3').show();
        $('#plaat4').show();
        $('#plaat5').hide();
        $('#plaat6').hide();
        $('#plaat7').hide();
    } 

    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '5') {
        $('#plaat1').show();
        $('#plaat2').show();
        $('#plaat3').show();
        $('#plaat4').show();
        $('#plaat5').show();
        $('#plaat6').hide();
        $('#plaat7').hide();
    } 

    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '6') {
        $('#plaat1').show();
        $('#plaat2').show();
        $('#plaat3').show();
        $('#plaat4').show();
        $('#plaat5').show();
        $('#plaat6').show();
        $('#plaat7').hide();
    } 

    if($('#plaatnum').val() == '7') {
        $('#plaat1').show();
        $('#plaat2').show();
        $('#plaat3').show();
        $('#plaat4').show();
        $('#plaat5').show();
        $('#plaat6').show();
        $('#plaat7').show();
    } 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned your settings, because big IF chains like that are gross.
Further, form values should be present on a reload, so use a documentready listener.

```
$(function() {
$('#plaat1 , #plaat2, #plaat3, #plaat4, #plaat5, #plaat6, 
#plaat7').hide(); 
function doStuff(){
   var storedValue = $('#plaatnum').val();
   for(var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      if(i <= storedValue) {
         $('#plaat' + i).show(); 
      } else {
         $('#plaat' + i).hide();
      }
   }
}
$('#plaatnum').change(doStuff);
$(document).ready(doStuff);
});
```